# How do I plot current time on X axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Hi I am trying to plot(matplotlib) live data from a DHT11 Temp sensor to a graph.

```
x = current time
y = temperature
```

I import datetime as dt

then use

```
xs.append(dt.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

But I keep on getting

> "//ValueError: could not convert string to float: '22:20:02.817201'//"

I don't know what else to try.
thx
Lappies

Comment: You don't show any of the code that is responsible for the error. (See [mcve]) One cannot know what you are trying that fails. Possibly you simply don't want to convert your date to a string, but who knows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

now=dt.datetime.now()
delta=dt.timedelta(seconds=5)
times=[now+delta*i for i in range(10)]
temps=np.arange(10)**2

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.plot(times,temps)
fig.show()
```

If you want to play with the formatting of the time axis, use `import matplotlib.dates as mdates` and something like `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S\n%b-%d'))`

Comment: Thanks I got the dates sorted Andrei, Now Im struggeling to make this a "live" graph...please tell me you have an idea?

Comment: You can always update the times and temperature arrays. But you need to explain how the live part occurs. Do you keep all times or do you keep only the last few minutes?  Anyway, I think that would deserve to be a different question

Comment: So I live on the Zambezi river and I am measuring the river level with a HC-SR04 ultrasonic distance sensor and Temp and Humidity with a DHT 11 sensor connected to an RPi. I got the "Live graph" sorted this afternoon.. now I want to make a graph displaying the River level for the entire year'Histogram' and another displaying the level for the month. I store all data in a csv "Date , Temp ect.". Question is how can I create a new Csv start of every month?

Comment: Is the csv updated somehow automatically? If you do it by hand, you can also create a new one by hand. Otherwise, you can just use `pandas` to sort your csv by month